# How to create a list in Python, based of another master list and user input as index?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python.

I have a list like

```
Master = ['Apple','Banana','Clementines','Dates','Fig','Guava']
```

I would like to get user input like

```
Choose your fruits:
> 1,3:5
```

Based on user input, I want to create a sub-list like

```
SelectedFruits = ['Apple','Clementines','Dates','Fig']
```

If I perform command as follows, I get an error that the index is a string.

```
UserInput = input()
SelectedFruits = Master[UserInput]
```

Can you kindly help?

Comment: Does the inputs added one by one, or entered in the same time with a comma like you used ?

Comment: What does `1,3:5` mean?

Comment: so if you pick 1,3,5 the should be `SelectedFruits =['Banana','Dates','Guava']` ?

Comment: Just so you know, Python iterators are zero-indexed.

Comment: @devtye, there is a colon between 3 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```
Master = ['Apple','Banana','Clementines','Dates','Fig','Guava']
inp = input().split(",")
# input is "1,3:5"
SelectedFruits = []
for elem in inp:
    if ":" in elem:
        i, j = elem.split(":")
        SelectedFruits.extend(Master[int(i):int(j)])
    else:
        i = int(elem)
        SelectedFruits.append(Master[i])
# ['Banana', 'Dates', 'Fig']
```

Assuming the input is entered one time with commas, you can split them first, then put in a for loop.

What I did in the solution is to check for **":"** s in each input to see if it is an index. Then I stack them in a tuple as such **(i,j)** to later use as indexes because tuple cannot be used directly as index.

And take care that every the time we use these values we have to convert them to integers because default inputs are always strings.

```
SelectedFruits.extend(Master[int(i):int(j)])
```

I used extend(), instead of append() in this part because the indexes we use, causes it to return another list inside list so it would look like this if we hadn't done that:

```
['Banana', ['Dates', 'Fig']]
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this solution and it worked. I did change the line SelectedFruits.extend(Master[int(i):int(j)]) to SelectedFruits.extend(Master[int(i):int(j)+1])

Comment: No problem. Please take a look at the other answer as well, it uses a different way to concatenate lists.

Comment: @BalajiRamanathan: Consider checking out Python's PEP-008 for some Python-specific naming conventions and other guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

The user passes a comma separated list of ranges so we'll need to parse this.

```
master = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Clementines', 'Dates', 'Fig', 'Guava']
user_input = input()
new_list = []
for index in user_input.split(","):
    if ":" in index:
        start, end = index.split(":")
        new_list += master[int(start):int(end)]
    else:
        new_list += [master[int(index)]]
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thanks @rtemperv. I will try this answer as well.